# (Proof Verification) Prove that $X$ is connected if and only if the only subsets of $X$ that are clopen are $X$ and ∅

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness

I have proven that if $X$ and $\emptyset$ are the only open and closed sets then $X$ is connected as follows by contradiction:

Let $X$ and $\emptyset$ be the only open and closed sets and let $X$ be disconnected then there $\exists$ A,B $\subset X$ such that $A \cup B = X$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. This implies that $A = B^{c}$ and $B = A^{c}$. But since B is open then $A$ is closed, and since A is open then B is closed which is a contradiction.

However the fact that if X is connected then $X$ and $\emptyset$ are the only clopen sets is not as clear to me. I have tried to prove it by contradiction as well: Assuming that $X$ is connected and that 
$\exists$ A $\subset X$ such that A is clopen. However I do not know how to continue the proof.

Comment: If $A$ is clopen then $A$ and $A^c$ are both open.

Comment: I understand that, but if $A^{c}$ is open then A is closed and viceversa, which would not solve the problem.

Comment: But you are assuming that $A$ is clopen, i.e., both closed and open. Therefore $A^c$ is also both closed and open.

Comment: And how would that be a contradiction?

Comment: $X = A \cup A^c$ and $A \cap A^c = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume some non-trivial $A$ is clopen in $X$.  Then $A$ and $A^c$ are both non-empty open sets in $X$.  Therefore, $A\cup A^c=X$ is a non-trivial separation of $X$ into disjoint open sets.  Therefore, $X$ is not connected.